# Java exception [SWITCH && SCANNER]

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I was trying to make my first java program with the use of switches and scanners, but I just can’t fix the error that returns me.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Operazioni.main(Operazioni.java:13)
```

**Code:**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operazioni{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int risultato;
        int select;
        int num1,num2;
        Scanner oggetti = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Che operazione vuoi effettuare?");
        System.out.println("1. Addizione, 2. Sottrazione, 3. Moltiplicazione 4. Divisione");
        select = oggetti.nextInt();
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
        System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
        num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
        num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
        risultato = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("Il risultato dell'addizione è " + risultato);
        case 2:
        System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
        num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
        num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
        risultato = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("Il risultato della sottrazione è " + risultato);
        break;
        case 3:
        System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
        num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
        num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
        risultato = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println("Il risultato della moltiplicazione è " +risultato);
        case 4:
        System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
        num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
        num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
        risultato = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println("Il risultato della divisione è " + risultato);
        default:
        System.out.println("Errore, scelta non esistente");
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive me for the bad order in writing the code.

Comment: What do you input when you get this error?

Comment: (1) you need to `break` flow of control starter in some case or it will try to execute code of rest of cases after it (2) let your editor / IDE indent code for you.

Comment: Also which line is 13? Based on posted code it will be `switch (select)` but there is no Scanner involved there.

Comment: Note that since you input `num1` and `num2` for every operation, you could take that out of the `switch` (do it before) and simplify your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch-case syntax is missing the break; statements
Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operazioni {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int risultato;
        int select;
        int num1, num2;
        Scanner oggetti = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Che operazione vuoi effettuare?");
        System.out.println("1. Addizione, 2. Sottrazione, 3. Moltiplicazione 4. Divisione");
        select = oggetti.nextInt();
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato dell'addizione è " + risultato);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato della sottrazione è " + risultato);
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato della moltiplicazione è " + risultato);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato della divisione è " + risultato);

        default:
            System.out.println("Errore, scelta non esistente");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? Braces aren't required for case statements.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct although you forgot adding break statements in case 1,3 & 4

you have used scannerobj.nextInt() to read user input, **nextInt() method of scanner class, Reads a int value from the user**, I'm guessing in your case user is inputting string instead of integer that leads to this error

Here is the working code(output SS attached):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int risultato;
        int select;
        int num1,num2;
        Scanner oggetti = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Che operazione vuoi effettuare?");
        System.out.println("1. Addizione, 2. Sottrazione, 3. Moltiplicazione 4. Divisione");
        select = oggetti.nextInt();
        switch (select) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato dell'addizione è " + risultato);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato della sottrazione è " + risultato);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato della moltiplicazione è " +risultato);
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Inserisci il primo numero");
            num1 = oggetti.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Inserisci il secondo numero");
            num2 = oggetti.nextInt();
            risultato = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println("Il risultato della divisione è " + risultato);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Errore, scelta non esistente");
        }

    }

}
```

[image]